# Catch AccountStatusException

Tags: php, security, symfony, symfony-2.1

I would like to implement a custom logic for my users implementing the [AdvancedUserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.html)

I would like to allow non-enabled users to access some zones (like the account zone where they can change their e-mail if they made a mistake).

According to the documentation :

> If any of the methods in this interface return false, authentication
>   will fail.
>
> If you need to perform custom logic for any of these situations, then
>   you will need to register an exception listener and watch for the
>   specific exception instances thrown in each case. All exceptions are a
>   subclass of AccountStatusException

So I tried to create a Listener by adapting [this cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) to the security events :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Listener;


use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;

class NecdocPatientExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException($event)
    {
        // Handle event code goes here
    }
}
```

And I've added it to the bundle's services.xml :

```
services:
    kernel.listener.acme_user_exception_listener:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\AcmeExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.success, method: onKernelException }
```

This catches **AuthenticationFailureEvent** (the onKernelException is called) but not **AccountStatusException** (the onKernelException is not called)

I've been looking to the Security component code, and it seems that exceptions are caught without triggering any events.
Is there a way to catch those exceptions anyways ?

Comment: Please add the body if the `onKernelException($event)` function. This event listener will do nothing right now.

Comment: The problem is that the onKernelException method is never called. Adding a body won't do anything in this case.

Comment: I've changed my strategy and used role-access instead of implementing the AdvancedUserInterface, because the implementation looks like it doesn't send events...

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;

class AcmeExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // We get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $message = 'My Error says: ' . $exception->getMessage() . ' with code: ' . $exception->getCode();

        // Customize our response object to display our exception details
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($message);

        // Checks that the exception is an account status exception
        if ($exception instanceof AccountStatusException) {
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(500);
        }

        // Send our modified response object to the event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```